# Layers displaced after QGIS update

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, convert, update

I am using QGIS 3.16 on a MacOS Sierra 10.12.6. Since I updated from QGIS 2.18 (I was not using this program for a long time) the layers or the base maps are displaced by several meters.

The project reference system is EPSG: 2039 New Israeli Grid, the layers are saved as such, the base maps (Bing Aerial, Google Maps etc) are in WGS 84 or other reference systems.

Probably the maps are not converted correctly. Does somebody know the problem and can tell me what to do? In easy language?

Comment: Please illustrate the displacement by providing a screenshot.

Comment: The problem is most likely with the plugin that download and display the basemaps. For example, these types of errors were very common with the OpenLayers plugin. If that's the case, make sure you uninstall it as it brings multiple issues and install the QuickMapServices plugin to display basemaps.